# Android Chrome Website

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, web

Guys I build a website and when i am accessing it from the android browser(Default) A script that is very important on the functionality of my website is not being displayed. But when  I am accessing it from the android google chrome browser the script is being displayed as I was expected to see.

My site is responsive, it adapted to the screen of the user.

I am using galaxy note 2 and the android version is 4.3.

I was thinking to build an android application such as a browser that is going to be always fullscreen and locked on my site but i do not what google chrome browser has and making my website as I want it to be.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by Android Browser (default). Is there a Samsung Browser already preinstalled on the phone that isn't Chrome?

My guess, off the top of my head, is that JavaScript is disabled on this other browser. If you were to create your own browser with an Android WebView, JavaScript is disabled by default and must be manually set to `true`.

A quick Google search for 'Samsung Note JavaScript' doesn't return anything readily apparent, but here are a few different Samsung Models with directions on how to enable JavaScript on their browsers. I would imagine the process is similar for the Note 2.

http://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-6782

http://www.droidista.com/2014/06/enabledisable-javascript-on-samsung.html

http://www.att.com/esupport/article.jsp?sid=KB117209&cv=820#fbid=omMGs_GnNUf